# How to copy a single postgresql table using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to copy the table before deleting it using pgAdmin 4 v4. Here is the query I used.

```
copy table_name to 'C:\tmp\backup.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

But I got error message.

> ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_write_server_files role to COPY to a file
> HINT: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
> SQL state: 42501

I used

```
\copy table_name to 'C:\tmp\backup.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

query, but there was error at `\copy`.
Does anyone know how to copy table as a file (csv/sql)?

Comment: Which error was show at "but there was error at" ?

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Comment: This error was shown.

Comment: The statement a shown works for me, tested on Windows

Comment: It didn’t work for me. I also tested on windows.

Comment: i overlooked the pgadmin., i just tested with pgsql

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `\copy` in pgAdmin, because `\copy` is a [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) command, whereas `COPY` is a SQL command.

Comment: Either use psql or ask for the `pg_write_server_files` privilege, as the error message says you should do.